# AES encrypt-decrypt two-way (Arduino -> Node , Node -> Arduino)

Tags: encryption, arduino, aes

I've managed to get him to encrypt and decrypt from (Node-Arduino).

From node I can also encrypt, but when I want to decrypt from arduino, it gets incorrect characters.
In the code you can find both encryption and decryption of arduno and node.

**Arduino -> Node:**

*Encrypt Arduino*:

> Original menssage: "{ 'switchOnCooler': 'true' }"
>
> data: Ww5DkZXWXN3c9QDy4iEYQwfSP8wipQXuWZgJy567ZQdt9xL40WhAyGJsAAXAldun
>
> iv: MTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1AA==

*Decrypt Node*:

> { 'switchOnCooler': 'true' }

**Node ->  Arduino**:

*Encrypt Node*:

> Original menssage: "{'info': 'Hello stackoverflow'}"
>
> data: X6iXoxLdLItG3MmQ3Y407lwUYJW+T0Nwu7AIA5GDS+fSCK08KBycP0iNUy3x3AvU
>
> IV: 987654321098765

*Decrypt Arduino*:

> {'info': ⸮⸮⸮llo stackoverflow'}

Could someone help me?

Node Code:

```js
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
var AESKey = '2B7E151628AED2A6ABF7158809CF4F3C';


//----- FUNCTIONS --------

function decryptMessage(esp8266_iv, esp8266_msg) {
 var plain_iv =  new Buffer( esp8266_iv , 'base64').toString('hex');
 var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse( plain_iv );
 var key= CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse( AESKey );

 console.log("Let's ");

 // Decrypt
 try {
  var bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt( esp8266_msg, key , { iv: iv} );
  var plaintext = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
  var decoded_b64msg =  new Buffer(plaintext , 'base64').toString('ascii');
  var decoded_msg =     new Buffer( decoded_b64msg , 'base64').toString('ascii');
  console.log("Decryptedage: ", decoded_msg);

  var aux2 = JSON.parse(decoded_msg)
  return aux2
  
 }catch(error) {
  console.log("ERROR decrypt")
 }
}


function encryptMessage(messagePlain) {
    console.log("-----------------------")
    console.log("---- EncryptMessage ---")
    console.log("-----------------------")

    try {
        var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(AESKey);
        var ivPlain = "987654321098765"  // static IV
        var ivHex = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(ivPlain);
        var txtBase64 = new Buffer(messagePlain).toString('base64')    // ENCODE BASE 64 TEXT
        var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(txtBase64, key , { iv: ivHex });      
        encrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.base64)

  var request = require("request");

  var url = 'http://192.168.1.41/info?'+encrypted.toString()+'&'+ivPlain
     console.log("url ",url)

  request(url, function (error, response, body) { 
         console.log("Finish GET ")

        })
    }catch(error) {
        console.log("error ENCRYPT: "+error)
    } 
}
```

Arduino code:

```js
#include "AES.h"
#include <b64.h>


#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

AES aes;
AES aesDecript;
BaseS base64;


// The unitialized Initialization vector
byte my_iv[N_BLOCK] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
char b64data[200];
byte cipher[1000];
byte cipherDecrypt[1000];
byte iv [N_BLOCK] ;
byte key[] = { 0x2B, 0x7E, 0x15, 0x16, 0x28, 0xAE, 0xD2, 0xA6, 0xAB, 0xF7, 0x15, 0x88, 0x09, 0xCF, 0x4F, 0x3C };  

........

void encriptInfo(String message) { 
   
    Serial.println ("==================================================");
    Serial.println ("==================   ENCRYPT   ===================");
    Serial.println ("==================================================");
    // IV
    String ivRandom = "1234567890123456";
    byte ivByteArray[ivRandom.length()];
    ivRandom.getBytes(ivByteArray, ivRandom.length());


    char b64dataIV[200];
    base64.b64_encode( b64dataIV, (char *)ivByteArray, N_BLOCK);
    String iv = String(b64dataIV);
    Serial.println ("IV: " + iv);

    
    // encript message  
    int b64len = base64.b64_encode(b64data, (char *)message.c_str(),message.length()); 
    aes.do_aes_encrypt((byte *)b64data, b64len , cipher, key, 128, ivByteArray);

    
    // DATA encripted
    base64.b64_encode(b64data, (char *)cipher, aes.get_size() );
    String data = String(b64data);

    Serial.println ("Data: " + data);

    request(data, iv);    
}

void decrypt(String b64data, String IV_base64) { 
    Serial.println ("==================================================");
    Serial.println ("==================   DE- CRYPT   =================");
    Serial.println ("==================================================");
  
  char data_decoded[300];
  char iv_decoded[300];
  byte out[300];
  char temp[300];

  // data
  b64data.toCharArray(temp, 300);
  int encrypted_length = base64.b64_decode(data_decoded, (char *)b64data.c_str(), b64data.length());


  // IV
  IV_base64.toCharArray(temp, 300);
  base64.b64_decode(iv_decoded, temp, IV_base64.length());


  // DECRIPT
  aes.do_aes_decrypt((byte *)data_decoded, 50, out, key, 128, (byte *)iv_decoded);
  
  char message[100];
  base64.b64_decode(message, (char *)out, aes.get_size());


    String plain_text = String(message);
  Serial.println("messageUT");
  Serial.println(message);
}
```

Comment: You should be using base64-url if you want to use base 64 in a GET request. Probably the IV value is affected because data is lost and that changes the first decrypted block. Using base 64 for the plaintext is utterly unnecessary though. Just specify a good character encoding such as UTF-8 or - if the text is simple English - US-ASCII.

Comment: Good morning,
I tried to make the request on base64, but I can't find any documentation on how to do that. Can you help me?

Comment: Well, you can just replace the two characters with the other two characters (`+` with `-` and `/` with `_`) and remove the equals sign to go from base64 to base64url. That's of course less efficient then just using the correct base64url alphabet in the first place. A quick search shows a [stream lib](https://github.com/Naguissa/b64StreamLib) but you'll have to test for yourself.

Comment: Ok.... It's solved... the problem was that I need send IV from node in hexadecimal

> Last: 
        var ivPlain = "987654321098765"
> Solved: 
        var ivPlain = "ABCDFF450405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F"